# How to make sure results from my query are continuous

Tags: sql

I want to query a table that has account numbers but I need a sequential range of 60000 starting from any number, it doesn't matter as long as it is sequential.

I cannot come up with anything, I have just a basic between query but this is not even good because I don't want or need to specify a start, just need the sequential range.

```
Select *
From tableA
where account number between acctNum1 and acctNum2;
```

A continuous range of 60000 account numbers.

So if there are account numbers from 1 to 1 million and there are random gaps in the account numbers, I  want to see if I can get a qty of 60000 but sequential.

Comment: Are you saying that if there is no record in the table, you want an account number returned anyway?  I'm assuming there are other columns in this table, what should they look like given that situation?

Comment: You need to provide sample data and desired results.  Why wouldn't account numbers be sequential?  (Presumably that is what you mean by "continuous" because account numbers are by their nature discrete.)

Comment: Account number table with various information like status, owner, date, etc., but of course there are account numbers.  Now, first account number is 1, then 2, then 3 and as they were generated, they were continuous, so imagine a table was generated with 1 to 1,000,000  for the account numbers.  People can assign from this table, so in 1 to 1 million there can be any missing.  So 1201 can be available and 1202 but then 1203 is not so there is no continuous range there between 1201 and 1204.  I need to get any start account num and any end as long as there are sequential with count of 60,000.

Comment: You problem is called "gaps and islands" please read this: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/ and edit your question with more details about your problem adding sample data showing what you see as a problem and how would you want it resolved.

Comment: I cannot give data as this is sensitive data but I am not sure how I can make it any more clearer.  Account table has a lot of columns which are all irrelevant except for account number.  Here again is my ideal query but in words.  "Select from the account table where account number sequential and count of 60000" I will read the article you posted.  Thank you.

Comment: Maybe editing the question with a small sample set of numbers like 1,3,4,7 and then the desired output of the select given those few numbers would help illustrate the problem?

Comment: To be clear: You require an arbitrary starting number of N, and require that each and every record containing  N+1, N+2, N+3, to N+59999 all exist without gaps?

Comment: And there might be many blocks of 60000 that fulfill this requirement, and the starting number could be nondeterministic?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

The below returns a list of all possible ranges having 60,000 sequential records.

it returns 3 columns a StartAcct#, a RN and a EndAcct#.  The start and end's define the range you could use.

```
WITH CTE2 as (SELECT *, row_number() over (order by accountNumber) RN FROM SrcTable)
   , CTE3 as (SELECT AccountNumber as StartAcct#
                   , RN, LEAD(AccountNumber,60000-1) over(order by rn) as EndAcct#
              FROM CTE2 A)

SELECT * 
FROM CTE3
WHERE EndAcct#-StartAcct# = 60000-1
```

For example may return: (if gap of 20 is what you're looking for)...

```
+----+------------+----+----------+
|    | StartAcct# | RN | EndAcct# |
+----+------------+----+----------+
|  1 |         26 | 24 |       46 |
|  2 |         27 | 25 |       47 |
|  3 |         28 | 26 |       48 |
+----+------------+----+----------+
```

- Adjust SrcTable to be table with accountNUmber
- Assumes AccountNumber is actually numeric, you indicated started w/ 1 and went up sequentially by 1 from there...
- assumes you have lead window function/analytic available to you.

Not too sure about performance...  as materializing a cte for 1,000,000 records and assigning a row number to each may not be the most efficient thing in the world...

[Rextester Example](https://rextester.com/TURA31977) using 100 records with a gap returns all records having a gap of 20, adjusting 20 to 60,000 is pretty straight forward and the 20 was just a proof of concept.

Now that we have a start and end range, we can get the 60,000 records in question.  Simply by querting the base table where the accountNumber is between start and end... by cross joining to the CTE3 having limited it to just 1 record...

Notes:
[Does SQL Server TOP stop processing once it finds enough rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688508/does-sql-server-top-stop-processing-once-it-finds-enough-rows)  Seems to indicate Top may early exit if you're just after a first occurrence... but I find that hard to believe since an order has to be applied...

So testing would have to be done to know if top or limit could benefit the query.

Other attempts to answer feel free to leverage sample created!

Comment: Pretty darned clever solution, if I do say my darned self :)

Comment: Just taking advantage of Lead()'s offset abliity.

Comment: Oops I was giving 60001... needed to subtract one from 60000  but the concept was still sound :P

Answer (score 0):

Before I was able to try the above answer I found this and it worked great for me.   Thank you to everyone!

[Find ranges from a series of numbers in SQL/Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717264/find-ranges-from-a-series-of-numbers-in-sql-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT OVER` with a range window clause to see how many rows are in the range of account_number - 59999 and itself. Pick the first number that has a full count of 60000 and select from the table accordingly.

```
select *
from mytable
where 
(
  select min(account_number)
  from
  (
    select
      account_number,
      count(*) over (order by account_number range between 59999 preceding and current row) as cnt
    from mytable
  ) viewed
  where cnt = 60000
) between account_number and account_number + 59999
order by account_number;
```

Comment: I tried this and it just runs and runs, I killed it after about 8 minutes so not sure if there is an error or it just takes more time.

Comment: Well, depending on your hardware, such a query can run a long time. First, all rows must be sorted, which can be time consuming - especially when you are short on memory. Then the DBMS must loop back for each and every row until it reaches account_number - 59999. This is also a lot of work. I am sure that xQberts idea to simply look forward or back exactly 59999 rows and check whether that particular row holds the desired value must be way faster.

Comment: awe shucks :P  I think mine would operate ok if there's an index on accountNumber.  I can't see it being too slow in that case other than having to generate a row number for all account numbers....... I wonder if the index already does that though... bah I'm too lazy to check ;P